# Can you make nohup.out get created only on errors without manually specifying the file name?

Tags: io-redirection, nohup

Can you make `nohup ./file $1 $2 &` (which runs `./file` in the background) create `nohup.out` only for errors and not for standard output?

But please without manually specifying `nohup.out` i.e.

```
nohup ./file $1 $2 >/dev/null 2>nohup.out &
```

Also, the following states `nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout` and redirects neither output nor errors. I assume it's because it tells it to redirect errors to output but output is redirected to /dev/null:

```
nohup ./file $1 $2 >/dev/null &
```

Comment: Can you explain why `nohup ./file $1 $2 >/dev/null 2>nohup.out &` isn't good enough? I mean, that's the normal way, either that or `nohup ./file > out 2>error` or similar.

Comment: Due to having to manually mention the file name. And if the default file name is changed in the future, it won't reflect that.

Comment: OK. I have personally _never_ used `nohup.out` since I always want to define my output file names to ensure that old runs aren't overwritten by new ones.

Comment: At least for now it only appends anyway, plus maybe some people do want to overwrite to avoid piling up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `man nohup` states:

> If  standard input is a terminal, redirect it from an unreadable file.  If standard output is a terminal, append output to `nohup.out` if possible, `$HOME/nohup.out` otherwise. If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output. To save output to FILE, use `nohup COMMAND > FILE`

Since you are running this in a terminal, standard error will be redirected to standard output, and you will not be able to do this without specifying the filename as suggested in your OP.